# Symfony 2.8 issue when i run config.php

Tags: symfony

[image] when i access config.php in my browser i have following issue.

Configuration Checker

This script analyzes your system to check whether is ready to run Symfony applications.

RECOMMENDATIONS

To enhance your Symfony experience, it’s recommended that you fix the following:

intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (4.2.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)

To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install driver by :

if you use php5 do:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

if you use php7 :

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

After restart apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: ok. But that's not a serious problem. So you can continue to develop your application pending to find  a solution.